# Ford Ka - Passenger footwell water leak

Tags: ford, water-leak, ka

Ford Ka 2005 - Has developed a water leak in the passeneger footwell. Car has been back to garage, couple of times now but problem persists.

---

**Edit**

I've lost count the amount of times the car has been back to the garage now and it is still leaking. Not as much as it was but it is still leaking.

The garage report they cannot locate the leak and keep adding more sealant each visit but after heavy rain there will be a small pool of water on the floor - passenger side. The carpet is still out.

To confirm it is definitely rain water and not coolant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If this vehicle has air conditioning, I'd bet the condensation drain tube is plugged. When this happens, the excess water which collects has no where to go but into the passenger side foot well. To fix this, you need to find the drain tube which should stick down under the car on the passenger side of the engine bay (can only be accessed from below). When you locate it, put a long thin wire up the tube until you clear the blockage. You'll know it's unblocked when you get water out of the tube (presuming the A/C has been ran recently).

Answer (score 1):

Is the leak 'rain water' or 'engine coolant'? If you can smell a sweet smell inside the car and have a lot of internal misting of the vehicles windows them you proberbly have a heater radiator leak. Also on the bulk head in the engine compartment you will find the heater control valve which can cause leakage into the vehicle after the coolant runs around the bodywork under the bonnet. Also, the bonding of the windscreen to the body is a source of water leaks. Check the drain on the bulk head, a rubber tube affair hanging down from the bodywork behind the rear of the engine. They can become blocked with silt and flood the bulkhead, especially after heavy rain. Firstly though you need to determine if if is rainwater or coolant that constitutes the leak.